# Android: SlidingMenu change content

Tags: android, fragment, slidingmenu

I'm using SlidingMenu with a ListView as a menu and I want to change the content of my MainActivity dynamically based on the click of a ListView element. I know that I have to use Fragments to achieve this.

I have a PlayerFragment with nothing in it yet:

```
public class PlayerFragment extends Fragment {

 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, 
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_player_fragment, container, false);
    }

}
```

And my standard MainActivity with a SlidingMenu in it:

```
public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity {

private ListView mainListView;
private ArrayAdapter<String> listAdapter;
private SlidingMenu menu;
protected ListFragment mFrag;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);




    menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidth(8);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.8f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setBehindWidth(600);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu_frame);

    mainListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);

    String[] planets = new String[] { "News", "Android", "Control",
            "About" };
    ArrayList<String> planetList = new ArrayList<String>();
    planetList.addAll(Arrays.asList(planets));

    listAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            R.layout.custom_list_element, R.id.title, planetList);

    mainListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    mainListView.setSelector(R.layout.listselector);

    mainListView
            .setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                        int position, long id) {
                    String item = String.valueOf(mainListView
                            .getItemAtPosition(position));

                }
            });



}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (menu.isMenuShowing()) {
        menu.toggle();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

How do I call the standard fragment when the app starts? And how do I change the fragment based on the click of the ListView?

I thought of something like this:

```
   if (fragment == null) {

           FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
           ft.add(R.id.RELATIVEVIEW_ID_HERE, new BasicFragment());
           ft.commit(); 
   }
```

and to change the Fragment this:

```
Fragment fg = NewsFragment.newInstance();
getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.RELATIVEVIEW_ID_HERE, fg).commit();
```

Is this correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ft.replace(...)` for all your `Fragment` changes, including displaying the first one, like so:

```
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
MyFragment myFragment = myFragment.newInstance();
ft.replace(android.R.id.content, myFragment).commit();
```

Comment: @GunnarKarlsson: Please help me i want to set new fragment on expandablelist' child click  using frangmentTransaction and  i dont want to use android.support.v4 . Can U please help me.?